# jeoQuery problem - Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

Tags: geonames

I am trying to use jeoQuery by Thomas Haukland to add an autocomplete function to my registration system and then place a map marker on an OpenLayers map.  However, upon running his code in my chrome browser I am getting the subject error.  Funny thing is that Safari doesn't report the error.  I cannot for the life of me see why this won't work in Chrome.

HTML:

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>

<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <title>JeoQuery - index.html</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jeoquery.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.1/themes/redmond/jquery-ui.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/ui-lightness/jquery-ui.css">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/prettify/188.0.0/prettify.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jeoquery.js"></script>
    <style type="text/css">
        #map{
            width:150px;
            height:150px;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body class="container">
    <div class="row well forms-horizontal" id="cityAutocomplete">
        <label for="city">Your location:
            <input class="input-large" id="city" type="text" placeholder="Begin typing your city/town..."/>
        </label>
    </div>
    <script>
        $(function () {
            $("#city").jeoCityAutoComplete({callback: function(city) { if (console) console.log(city);}});
        });
    </script>
    <div id="output">
        <p id="outputcontent">Your selection will be displayed here.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="map"></div>
</body>
```

Javascript:

```js
/* 
 * jeoQuery v0.5.1
 *
 * Copyright 2012-2038, Thomas Haukland
 * MIT license.
 *
 */

var jeoquery = (function ($) {
  var my = {};

  my.defaultData = {
    userName: 'demo',
    lang: 'en'
  };
  my.defaultCountryCode = 'US';
  my.defaultLanguage = 'en';
  my.geoNamesApiServer = 'api.geonames.org';
  my.geoNamesProtocol = 'http';

  my.featureClass = {
    AdministrativeBoundary: 'A',
    Hydrographic: 'H',
    Area: 'L',
    PopulatedPlace: 'P',
    RoadRailroad: 'R',
    Spot: 'S',
    Hypsographic: 'T',
    Undersea: 'U',
    Vegetation: 'V'
  };

  my.getGeoNames = function(method, data, callback) {
    var deferred = $.Deferred();
    if (!method || !methods[method]) {
      throw 'Invalid geonames method "' + method + '".';
    }
    $.ajax({
      url: my.geoNamesProtocol + '://' + my.geoNamesApiServer + '/' + method + 'JSON',
      dataType: 'jsonp',
      data: $.extend({}, my.defaultData, data),
      // GeoNames expects "traditional" param serializing
      traditional: true,
      success: function(data) {
        deferred.resolve(data);
        if (!!callback) callback(data);
      },
      error: function (xhr, textStatus) {
        deferred.reject(xhr, textStatus);
        alert('Ooops, geonames server returned: ' + textStatus);
      }
    });
    return deferred.promise();
  };

  function formatDate(date) {
    var dateQs = '';
    if (date) {
      dateQs = date.getFullYear() + '-' + (date.getMonth() + 1) + '-' + date.getDate();
    }
    return dateQs;
  }

  var methods = {
    astergdem: {params: ['lat', 'lng'] },
    children: {params: ['geonameId', 'maxRows'] },
    cities: {params: ['north', 'south', 'east', 'west', 'lang'] },
    countryCode: {params: ['lat', 'lng', 'type', 'lang', 'radius'] },
    countryInfo: {params: ['country', 'lang'] },
    countrySubdivision: {params: ['lat', 'lng', 'level', 'lang', 'radius'] },
    earthquakes: {params: ['north', 'south', 'east', 'west', 'date', 'maxRows', 'minMagnitude'] },
    findNearby: {params: ['lat', 'lng', 'featureClass', 'featureCode', 'radius', 'style', 'maxRows'] },
    findNearbyPlacename: {params: ['lat', 'lng', 'radius', 'style'] },
    findNearbyPostalCodes: {params: ['lat', 'lng', 'radius', 'style', 'maxRows', 'country', 'localCountry', 'postalCode'] },
    findNearbyStreets: {params: ['lat', 'lng', 'radius', 'maxRows'] },
    findNearbyStreetsOSM: {params: ['lat', 'lng'] },
    findNearbyWeather: {params: ['lat', 'lng'] },
    findNearbyWikipedia: {params: ['lat', 'lng', 'radius', 'maxRows', 'country', 'postalCode'] },
    findNearestAddress: {params: ['lat', 'lng'] },
    findNearestIntersection: {params: ['lat', 'lng'] },
    findNearestIntersectionOSM: {params: ['lat', 'lng', 'radius', 'maxRows'] },
    findNearbyPOIsOSM: {params: ['lat', 'lng'] },
    get: {params: ['geonameId', 'lang', 'style'] },
    gtopo30: {params: ['lat', 'lng'] },
    hierarchy: {params: ['geonameId'] },
    neighbourhood: {params: ['lat', 'lng'] },
    neighbours: {params: ['geonameId', 'country'] },
    ocean: {params: ['lat', 'lng', 'radius'] },
    postalCodeCountryInfo: {params: [] },
    postalCodeLookup: {params: ['postalcode', 'country', 'maxRows', 'charset'] },
    postalCodeSearch: {params: ['postalcode', 'postalcode_startsWith', 'placename_startsWith', 'country', 'countryBias', 'maxRows', 'style', 'operator', 'charset', 'isReduced'] },
    search: {params: [ 'q', 'name', 'name_equals', 'name_startsWith', 'maxRows', 'startRow', 'country', 'countryBias', 'continentCode', 'adminCode1', 'adminCode2', 'adminCode3', 'featureClass', 'featureCode', 'lang', 'type', 'style', 'isNameRequired', 'tag', 'operator', 'charset', 'fuzzy'] },
    siblings: {params: ['geonameId'] },
    srtm3: {params: ['lat', 'lng'] },
    timezone: {params: ['lat', 'lng', 'radius', 'date'] },
    weather: {params: ['north', 'south', 'east', 'west', 'maxRows'] },
    weatherIcao: {params: ['ICAO'] },
    wikipediaBoundingBox: {params: ['north', 'south', 'east', 'west', 'lang', 'maxRows'] },
    wikipediaSearch: {params: ['q', 'title', 'lang', 'maxRows'] }
  };

  return my;
}(jQuery));

(function ($) {
  $.fn.jeoCountrySelect = function (options) {
    var el = this;
    $.when(jeoquery.getGeoNames('countryInfo'))
    .then(function (data) {
      var sortedNames = data.geonames;
      if (data.geonames.sort) {
        sortedNames = data.geonames.sort(function (a, b) {
          return a.countryName.localeCompare(b.countryName);
        });
      }
      // Insert blank choice
      sortedNames.unshift({countryCode:'', countryName:''});
      var html = $.map(sortedNames, function(c) {
        return '<option value="' + c.countryCode + '">' + c.countryName + '</option>';
      });
      el.html(html);
      if (options && options.callback) options.callback(sortedNames);
    });
  };

  $.fn.jeoPostalCodeLookup = function (options) {
    this.on("change", function () {
      var code = $(this).val();
      var country = options.country || jeoquery.defaultCountryCode;
      if (options.countryInput) {
        country = options.countryInput.val() || jeoquery.defaultCountry;
      }
      if (code) {
        jeoquery.getGeoNames('postalCodeLookup', {postalcode: code, country: country}, function (data) {
          if (data && data.postalcodes && data.postalcodes.length > 0) {
            if (options) {
              if (options.target) {
                options.target.val(data.postalcodes[0].placeName);
              }
              if (options.callback) {
                options.callback(data.postalcodes[0]);
              }
            }
          }
        });
      }
    });
  };

  $.fn.jeoCityAutoComplete = function (options) {
    this.autocomplete({
      source: function (request, response) {
        jeoquery.getGeoNames('search', {
          featureClass: jeoquery.featureClass.PopulatedPlace,
          style: ((options && options.style) ? options.style : "medium"),
          maxRows: 12,
          name_startsWith: request.term
        }, function (data) {
          response(function() {
            data.geonames = $.map(data.geonames, function (item) {
                var displayName = item.name + (item.adminName1 ? ", " + item.adminName1 : "") + ", " + item.countryName;
                if (options && options.displayNameFunc) {
                  displayName = options.displayNameFunc(item);
                  if (displayName === null)
                    return null;
                }
                return {
                  label: displayName,
                  value: displayName,
                  details: item
                };
            });
            if (options && options.preProcessResults) {
                options.preProcessResults(data.geonames);
            }
            return data.geonames;
          }());
        });
      },
      minLength: 2,
      select: function( event, ui ) {
        if (ui && ui.item && options && options.callback) {
          options.callback(ui.item.details);
        }
      },
      open: function () {
        $(this).removeClass("ui-corner-all").addClass("ui-corner-top");
      },
      close: function () {
        $(this).removeClass("ui-corner-top").addClass("ui-corner-all");
      }
    });
  };

})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Oh, and Chrome is telling me the error is occuring on line 32 of the jeoquery.js file.

Sorry about the formatting of the JS code.  I don't know what went wrong.

Comment: So the weird thing is I use VS Code and while running the debugger through Chrome, the code works without the subject error appearing.